# Miscellaneous characters in MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, hash, pdo, special-characters

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$query->bindValue(":username", $lName);
$query->bindValue(":password", imu($lPass));
var_dump(imu($lPass));
try {
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

I'm trying to select the users id, depending on if they entered a valid login. I tried to just use "WHERE username = :username" and that works, it returns the id, but when I add the password part, or only the password check, it returns null. I checked with var_dump as you can see and the password that it's dumping is correct, it exists in the database. The password is hashed with my own encryption system and it returns all kinds of characters. This specific password was: "®Ç+¥J:àhMaÕú¡HW".

I was wondering if there is anyway to get the id with the password check or do I have to edit my hash'er so it returns alphanumeric characters?

Comment: what is your tables and client encoding?

Answer (score 0):

> if there is anyway to get the id with the password check

yes.

> do I have to edit my hash'er so it returns alphanumeric characters?

no.

The only issue with certain characters that can be is their encoding.

Make your password field either `[var]binary()` or make its collation `utf8_bin`

Comment: Okay, I set the whole database's collation to utf8_bin, it still doesn't work?

Comment: setting whole database's collation to utf8_bin would be terrible idea. you have to set this collation to password field only